# Insert html content into iFrame before the iFrame page contents

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I want to insert html content into iFrame. Requirement is I want to insert/append this content before iFrame Page contents. 
I have following sample code. Currently I used append function which appends new contents after Iframe page contents.

**TestPage.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <title>Test Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe id="sampleIframe" src="PopupPage.html" width="400" height="150"></iframe>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#sampleIframe').load(function () {
            var myFrame = $('#sampleIframe').contents().find('body');
            myFrame.append('<div><h3>Hello, World</h3></div>');
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**PopupPage.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Popup Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    You are on popup page.  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there's also something like prepend

```
 parent.insertBefore(el, parent.firstChild);
```

it will prepend to the first child of your parent

OR use jQuery equivalent

`$(parent).prepend(el)`
So your code would look like this:

```
myFrame.prepend($('<div><h3>Hello, World</h3></div>'));
```

Comment: I tried both insertBefore and prepend as 1) $('<div><h3>Hello, World</h3></div>').insertBefore(myFrame); 2) myFrame.prepend($('<div><h3>Hello, World</h3></div>'));  and find that prepend works for me. insertBefore also work but it insert the contents before iFrame <body> tag. Thanks :)